# Center horizontally child elements if their parent's width is 300% but each child's width 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

I have a dynamic slider with two buttons left and right.
that means for each slide, the slide parent **width increases by 100%. 2 slides * 100% = 200%.** `In example class="slider"; width:'200%'`

I want to center each slide's text in the middle of the page. But i want the text to slide not in just slides container, but in its parent-parent width (`class='carousel'` in example).

Code below, is example how the slider is looking right now.

**JavaScript, you should ignore this. Implemented it, for the code to work.**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //Display function after HTML is loaded

  const left = document.querySelector('.left');
  const right = document.querySelector('.right');

  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  var leftImg = document.getElementById('left');
  var rightImg = document.getElementById('right');
  var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.slide').length; // get number of slides
  var sectionIndex = 1;

  slider.style.width = ' ' + 100 * sections + '%';

  function changeOpacity() {
    if (sectionIndex == 1) {
      leftImg.style.opacity = '0.4';
    } else {
      leftImg.style.opacity = '1';
    }
    if (sectionIndex == sections) {
      rightImg.style.opacity = '0.4';
    } else {
      rightImg.style.opacity = '1';
    }

  }

  left.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var leftImg = document.getElementById('left');
    sectionIndex = (sectionIndex > 1) ? sectionIndex - 1 : 1;
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(' + (sectionIndex - 1) * (-100 / sections) + '%)';
    changeOpacity();
  });

  right.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sectionIndex = (sectionIndex < sections) ? sectionIndex + 1 : sections;
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(' + (sectionIndex - 1) * (-100 / sections) + '%)';
    changeOpacity();
  });

})
```

```css
.slider-container {
  padding: 25px 0px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider-container .carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  border:solid 2px black;
  position:relative;
}

.slider-container .slider {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.slider-container .slider .slide {
  width: 100%;
}


.slider-container .arrow-container {
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container mobile-container text-left">
  <div class="carousel relative">
    <div id="slider" class="slider">

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="author d-flex flex-column">
          <h3>Ken Ludden</h3>
          <span class="regularText">Director, Margot Fonteyn Academy                      of Ballet</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="author d-flex flex-column">
          <h3>Ken Ludden</h3>
          <span class="regularText">Director, Margot Fonteyn Academy                      of Ballet</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="arrow-container d-flex justify-content-between ">
        <div>
          <button class="left" id="left" style="opacity: 0.4;">Left                     </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="right" id="right">Right</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Snippet below is what i want. But i should be centered, and i don't know how.
I have tried using fl

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //Display function after HTML is loaded

  const left = document.querySelector('.left');
  const right = document.querySelector('.right');

  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  var leftImg = document.getElementById('left');
  var rightImg = document.getElementById('right');
  var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.slide').length; // get number of slides
  var sectionIndex = 1;

  slider.style.width = ' ' + 100 * sections + '%';

  function changeOpacity() {
    if (sectionIndex == 1) {
      leftImg.style.opacity = '0.4';
    } else {
      leftImg.style.opacity = '1';
    }
    if (sectionIndex == sections) {
      rightImg.style.opacity = '0.4';
    } else {
      rightImg.style.opacity = '1';
    }

  }

  left.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var leftImg = document.getElementById('left');
    sectionIndex = (sectionIndex > 1) ? sectionIndex - 1 : 1;
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(' + (sectionIndex - 1) * (-100 / sections) + '%)';
    changeOpacity();
  });

  right.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sectionIndex = (sectionIndex < sections) ? sectionIndex + 1 : sections;
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(' + (sectionIndex - 1) * (-100 / sections) + '%)';
    changeOpacity();
  });

})
```

```css
.slider-container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px 0px;
}

.slider-container .carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 260px;
  width: 80%; /* the width i want */
  border: solid 2px black;  /* the border for your understading */
  position: relative;
}

.slider-container .slider {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.slider-container .slider .slide {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-container .comment {
  max-width: 352px;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.slider-container .arrow-container {
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container mobile-container text-left">
  <div class="carousel relative">
    <div id="slider" class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="author d-flex flex-column">
          <h3>Ken Ludden</h3>
          <span class="regularText">Director, Margot Fonteyn Academy of Ballet</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="author d-flex flex-column">
          <h3>Ken Ludden</h3>
          <span class="regularText">Director, Margot Fonteyn Academy of Ballet</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="arrow-container d-flex justify-content-between ">
        <div>
          <button class="left" id="left" style="opacity: 0.4;">Left                     </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="right" id="right">Right</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can see in this snippet that text is sliding from a **lot further right than the previous example**.
I need to center the slide, because i want the same for left side.
I have tried using `flex-column, align-items:center on class="slide".` And it works fine, but the `class="controls"` aren't centering because they are `position:absolute` and i tried to putting them elsewhere, but it didnt work..

I really hope you guys did understand what i want and really hope that i recieve atleast some suggestions. This is my 1st question, sorry for long code.
Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Your carousel is 80% of the width, so if you want that to be centered, you can do:  margin: 0 auto on the carousel class.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I get what you are saying. But i need the text and buttons in the center. If I put margin: 0 auto; It will center the carousel in the middle of page. But the Text and buttons will stay at the left side(at the start) inside of Carousel. This wont solve the problem

Comment: Well, for that, how about on the arrow-container class add: left: 0; right: 0; width:auto; text-align:center;

Or if going for the buttons on the same line look:
Remove - position: absolute;

Add - 
display: flex; justify-content: center;

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found a solution. WIth giving class="slide" flex, align-items:center , direction-column. And making adjustments to arrow-container.